# oracle query with groupby clause

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a upload table as follows:

bulk_upload_hist

```
id  file_name   doc_blob    upload_date upload_by
10  abc.pdf                 12-APR-21   123
11  xyz.pdf                 12-APR-21   123
```

inventory history stores the records from the file as follows:
inventory_doc_hist

```
id upload_id    upload_status   create_date     create_by   inv_doc_type
1   10          1               12-APR-21       123         20
2   10          1               12-APR-21       123         20
3   10          0               12-APR-21       123         10
4   10          1               12-APR-21       123         10
4   11          1               12-APR-21       123         20
5   11          0               12-APR-21       123         10
```

I want my output per bulk upload as follows:

```
id  file_name   successful/10   Successful/20   UnSuccessful    upload_date upload_by
10  abc.pdf     2               1               1               12-APR-21   123
11  xyz.pdf     1               1               0               12-APR-21   123
```

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `join` and conditional aggregation:

```
select buh.id, buh.file_name,
       sum(case when ih.inv_doc_type = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as num_successful_10,
       sum(case when ih.inv_doc_type = 20 then 1 else 0 end) as num_successful_20,
       sum(case when ih.inv_doc_type not in (10, 20) then 1 else 0 end) as num_successful_20,
       ih.upload_date, ih.upload_by
from bulk_upload_hist buh join
     inventory_history ih
     on ih.upload_id = ih.id
group by buh.id, buh.file_name, ih.upload_date, ih.upload_by;
```